QGIS triggers SQL queries involving ST_Intersects on non-geometric PostgreSQL tables, raising database errors
In QGIS 3.34.5, there are some wrong SQL queries in the log of the PostgreSQL database (13+3.4), each time I zoom in/out on a map having PostgreSQL layers, some of those being non-geometric tables:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," at character 72
STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM "my_schema"."feature_coded_values" WHERE ((ST_intersects(, ST_transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((2477206.05 1310560.81, 2847524.08 1315181.90, 2857747.45 1056410.86, 2467524.65 1053128.67, 2477206.05 1310560.81))', 2056), 0)))) LIMIT 0

I can easily guess that the part ST_intersects(,  is meant to accept a geometry feature before the comma, for geometric layer, but on tables with no geometries, it obviously fails.
Is there anything I can do to avoid running those queries on non-geometric tables in the database?

How did you add the table without geometry to the project?

https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#foreword-spatial-and-non-spatial-tables
